# Unable to bind socket on port 9997 -- is another session active?

Tags: gwt

I've had this problem come up several times in the past few days. I'm using FireFix 16.0.1 on a MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion using eclipse juno and the latest google plugin and SDK.

I'm testing my code, making small changes and reloading the page in FF. For some reason, FF cursor starts spinning and locks up, apparently in a loop. I force FF to quit and stop the development server but get this message when I restart the server. Last time this happened, I had to shutdown the os to clear the port. Closing the project and restarting eclipse did not do the job.

I know I have a workaround by picking a new port or randomly picking a port. What I want to know is how to stop FF when it gets into this state. Can I take a dump and send it somewhere or maybe debug the problem myself.

Answer (score 3):

When your cursor starts to spin, it means the OS is busy: you don't have to quit FF, just wait a little. You may resolve this problem by allocating more memory to Java and/or adding more RAM to your MacBook.

In any case, after you restart Firefox, your server in Eclipse is still running. So when you try to start the server again, you get an error message that the port is busy. There is a very simple solution: before you start the server again ("Debug as..." or "Run as..."), you should click on the red square in your Console or Development Mode tabs in Eclipse to terminate the previous launch. Also click on the two black X's next to the red square to remove terminated launches.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and the port remains allocated. I don't want to wait for FF to run out of memory but interrupt it, close down the test and start over. Thankfully, Chrome is back in service and I don't have the problem there.

Comment: If you face this problem again, downgrade to FF12. It looks like there is a memory leak somewhere in FF13 and later (I did not try 16 yet).

Comment: The problem may have been elsewhere. I mac was slowing down so I did a disk repair and it found some problems. I hope I'm back to snappy response time again. I'm also back to chrome now it's working again.